# How to format an output of saveAsTextFile?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am working on ETL process in Scala. My raw log files has many columns (around 70). I try to save it to file using Row() objects:

```
val base_RDD = rawData.map{r => if(r(13) == null || r(13).trim.isEmpty) Row(
    r(2), r(3), r(4), "", r(6), r(7), r(8), r(9), r(10), r(11), r(12), r(13), r(14), r(15), r(16), 
    r(18), r(21), r(27), r(29), r(30), r(32), r(33), r(34), r(35), r(36), r(37), r(38), r(39), r(40),
    r(41), r(42), r(43), r(44), r(45), r(46), r(47), r(48), r(49), r(50), r(51), r(52), r(53), r(54),
    r(55), r(56), r(57), r(58), r(59), r(60), r(61), r(62), r(63), r(64), r(65), r(66), r(67), r(68),
    r(69), r(70), r(71), r(72), r(73), r(74), r(75), "", "", "", "", "", "", "", r(76), r(77), r(78), r(1))
  else Row(r(2), r(3), r(4), "", r(6), r(7), r(8), r(9), r(10), r(11), r(12), r(13), r(14), r(15), r(16), 
    r(18), r(21), r(27), r(29), r(30), r(32), r(33), r(34), r(35), r(36), r(37), r(38), r(39), r(40), r(41), 
    r(42), r(43), r(44), r(45), r(46), r(47), r(48), r(49), r(50), r(51), r(52), r(53), r(54), r(55), r(56), r(57), r(58), 
    r(59), r(60), r(61), r(62), r(63), r(64), r(65), r(66), r(67), r(68), r(69), r(70), r(71), r(72), r(73), r(74), r(75), 
    r(13).split("_")(0), r(13).split("_")(1), r(13).split("_")(2), r(13).split("_")(3), r(5), r(13).split("_")(5), 
    r(13).split("_")(6),r(76), r(77), r(78), r(1))}
```

Now exception is gone. however "[" and "]" are observed after saving data on disk `base_RDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://nameservice1:8020/tmp/manish/tmpData")` Is my approach in correct way? please suggest what goes wrong? If any.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
[6035233,500212680,50013723,,,ddd.com,,,,,,,1,0,0,0,,0,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1x-1,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,0,0,]
[6035233,500212680,50013723,,,d.com,,,,,,,1,0,0,0,,0,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1x-1,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,0,0,]
```

I don't want "[" and "]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use plain `Lists` and make strings before you call `saveAsTextFile`:

```
rawData.map{r =>
  if(r(13) == null || r(13).trim.isEmpty) Seq(r(2), r(3), ...).mkString(",")
  else Seq(r(2), r(3), ...).mkString(",")
}
```